# How to remove specific lines from a file?

Tags: sed, terminal

I have a file (`ip.txt`) that contains ip rules

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 140.237.4.252 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 143.227.5.22 -j DROP

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 140.237.4.252 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 143.227.5.22 -j DROP
```

I am using below bash script (`removeip.sh`) to remove udp and tcp lines that belong to a specific IP from the `ip.txt` file .

```
function removeip(){
    ip="$1"        
    udprule="/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s "$ip" -j DROP"
    tcprule="/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s "$ip" -j DROP"
    sed --in-place /"$udprule"/d /root/ip.txt
    sed --in-place /"$udprule"/d /root/ip.txt     
}

removeip $1
```

When I use the below command in terminal

```
./removeip.sh 140.237.4.252
```

it throws

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 59: unterminated `s' command
```

What is the cause of this issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/` character is an operator in `sed`.  Basically you are ending up with:

```
sed '//sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s "{ip}" -j DROP/d' /root/ip.txt
```

This means that you are trying to execute '//sb' as a sed command, where `b` is the separator, and it cannot find another 'b'.

You would need to quote the special characters:

```
udprule="\/sbin\/iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s "$ip" -j DROP"
```

And you would need to watch out for what is in $ip for the same reason.

Comment: Alternatively, `sed` allows you to use any character instead of `/`. Pick one that wouldn't come up in the text. For example, `s_pattern_replacement_g` *should* work